# Comparing test ECG signals with ECG signals in database in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have two types of signals; test & database signals of roughly around 20 patients. I want to match test signal to correct patient as a part of verification and then calculate FAR,FRR & ERR. To verify the signal I am using corr2 function but it is not yielding correct results for any of the 20 patients.

`coef(1,i)=corr2(YY_t,ecgFltr);
[m,pl]=max(coef);
fprintf('The input signal matches with %s in the database',fileList{pl});`

This is a part of code, coef stores correlation coefficient with each file in database and the signal having maximum correlation coefficient with input signal will be answer?

Am I doing anything wrong here? Please correct.
If not then why I am not getting correct results?
Is there any other way too compare two ECG signals?

Comment: Before you can use correlation you're going to need to develop beat templates.  Otherwise something as simple as a change in heart rate will throw you off.  But this is not a programming question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it requires the expertise of a cardiologist or medical researcher, not a programmer.

Comment: perhaps something like DTW: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping. I think this is better asked on DSP.SE